# How to put text on polar chart using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

**This is a demo from the document of matplotlib**
[Scatter plot on polar axis](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-scatter-py)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Compute areas and colors
N = 150
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 200 * r**2
colors = theta

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
```

[image]

Now I want to replace these dots with some texts, like[image]

What modification should I do to these code?

Further more, I also want to put picture instead of texts, is that possible?

Thanks!!!
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the original code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# Compute areas and colors
N = 150
r = 2 * np.random.rand(N)
theta = 2 * np.pi * np.random.rand(N)
area = 200 * r**2
colors = theta

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')
c = ax.scatter(theta, r, c=colors, s=area, cmap='hsv', alpha=0.75)
```

If you add this two lines:

```
plt.text(0.67, 0.9, 'I am cartesian coordinate', transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
plt.text(np.pi, r[len(r)-1], 'I am polar coordinate')
```

You will get

[image]

and if you add this code:

```
im = Image.open('smurf.png')
newax = fig.add_axes([0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2], zorder=1)
newax.imshow(im)
newax.axis('off')
newax = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2], zorder=1)
newax.imshow(im)
newax.axis('off')
```

You will get

[image]

But it requires conversion calculation to get to polar coordinate

Answer (score 1):

You remove the `ax.scatter` part and instead use `ax.text`. But be aware that you need to pass the coordinates for the text also in polar coordinates. E.g.:
`ax.text(np.pi / 2, 60, 'people', fontsize=20, color='red')`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='polar')

for text,xytext, color in zip(*[['cat', 'car', 'people'],[(0.5, 0.3),(0.5, 0.7),(0.1, 0.5)],['b', 'g','r']]):
    ax.annotate(text,
                xy=(0,0),  # theta, radius
                xytext=xytext,    # fraction, fraction
                textcoords='figure fraction',
                horizontalalignment='left',
                verticalalignment='bottom',
                color=color,
                size=20
                )

plt.show()
```

[image]

For inserting images there is the following [demo](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/demo_annotation_box.html).